# How to trigger events by count in windowing for apache beam?

Tags: apache-beam, python-3.7, windowing

I appreciate if I could get help with `windowing` in `apache beam 2.13.0` .

I use `python 3.7.3` .

```
[ywatanabe@fedora-30-00 bdd100k-to-es]$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.3
```

I want to do exactly what this [example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing) is doing against **bounded data** though. Which is to group events by each trigger and pass it to next transform.

```
8.4.1.2. Discarding mode
If our trigger is set to discarding mode, the trigger emits the following values on each firing:

  First trigger firing:  [5, 8, 3]
  Second trigger firing:           [15, 19, 23]
  Third trigger firing:                         [9, 13, 10]
```

Referencing the example I have wrote my code as below,

```
    es = (gps | 'window:gps' >> WindowInto(
                   FixedWindows(1 * 60),
                   trigger=Repeatedly(
                       AfterAny(
                           AfterCount(1000000),
                           AfterProcessingTime(1 * 60)
                       )
                   ),
                   accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING
                   )
              | 'bulk:gps' >> beam.ParDo(BulkToESFn(esHost), tag_gps))
```

However in above code , it looks like the trigger is fired almost every millisec instead of every minute or 1,000,000 events.

```
2019-07-15 20:13:20,401 INFO Sending bulk request to elasticsearch. Doc counts: 11 Docs: {'track_id': '514df98862de83a07e7aff62dff77c3d', 'media_id': 'afe35b87-0a9acea6', 'ride_id': 'afe35b87d0b69e1928dd0a4fd75a1416', 'filename': '0a9acea6-62d6-4540-b048-41e34e2407c6.mov', 'timestamp': 1505287487.0, 'timezone': 'America/Los_Angeles', 'coordinates': {'lat': 37.786611081350365, 'lon': -122.3994713602353}, 'altitude': 16.06207275390625, 'vertical_accuracy': 4.0, 'horizantal_accuracy': 10.0, 'speed': 2.3399999141693115}
2019-07-15 20:13:20,403 INFO Sending bulk request to elasticsearch. Doc counts: 11 Docs: {'track_id': '514df98862de83a07e7aff62dff77c3d', 'media_id': 'afe35b87-0a9acea6', 'ride_id': 'afe35b87d0b69e1928dd0a4fd75a1416', 'filename': '0a9acea6-62d6-4540-b048-41e34e2407c6.mov', 'timestamp': 1505287488.0, 'timezone': 'America/Los_Angeles', 'coordinates': {'lat': 37.78659459994027, 'lon': -122.39945105706596}, 'altitude': 15.888671875, 'vertical_accuracy': 4.0, 'horizantal_accuracy': 10.0, 'speed': 2.3299999237060547}
2019-07-15 20:13:20,406 INFO Sending bulk request to elasticsearch. Doc counts: 11 Docs: {'track_id': '514df98862de83a07e7aff62dff77c3d', 'media_id': 'afe35b87-0a9acea6', 'ride_id': 'afe35b87d0b69e1928dd0a4fd75a1416', 'filename': '0a9acea6-62d6-4540-b048-41e34e2407c6.mov', 'timestamp': 1505287489.0, 'timezone': 'America/Los_Angeles', 'coordinates': {'lat': 37.78657796009011, 'lon': -122.39943055871701}, 'altitude': 15.741912841796875, 'vertical_accuracy': 4.0, 'horizantal_accuracy': 10.0, 'speed': 2.549999952316284}
```

Do I need any other option for windowing for this case ?

Answer (score 3):

I think window strategy and trigger strategy takes effect at the GBK step.
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing

In your case I think you can implement the DoFn(BulkToESFn) in a way that it buffers data and only writes to ES when count exceed a predefined value.

```
class BulkToESFn(DoFn):
  def __init__(self,
               batch_size=1000000):
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.batch = []

  def finish_bundle(self):
    self._flush()

  def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
    self.batch.append(element)
    if len(self.batch) >= self.batch_size:
      self._flush()

  def _flush(self):
    writeToES(self.batch)
    self.batch = []
```

Comment: This is a fabulous answer! I was unclear about what "bundles" actually are and how they're generated so I thought I'd add my research here. Turns out bundles are chunks of your data that get shipped to workers by the backend and you don't control how many elements are in a bundle. What's great about this code sample is that it will flush when batch fills up AND will flush at the end of that bundle to handle the case of a partially filled batch.

Comment: This does not work. In my case using the code above always execute _flush() only with finish_bundle. Since it's apache beam which sets the bundle size, I never reach batch_size.